# Ensure export compatibiliy with npm

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a npm module and I would like it to be importable by all kind of js client side app.

Right now I tried `export default myObject` and `module.exports = myObject`

The problem is `export default` seems to be available only in es6 app and `module.exports` doesn't work in pure javascript as module is not defined.

So I would like my module to be accessible if the client use React, Angular, Vue, pure Javascript or whatever... Also my module is just an object with a list of pure javascript functions inside. No tricky part here.

Is there a way to ensure that the module is available regardless of the technology the client will use ?

Comment: Can't you simply use `if (typeof module !=="undefined") {module.exports = yourExportedObject;}` at the end of your file?

Comment: first of all, module.exports is of no use if your considering the client side JavaScript applications. module.exports works with node.js.

Comment: That should work yes. And if I declare my object with `var myObj = {...}` and try to export it at the bottom of my file, will it become available also for pure javascript app ? As the export won't do anything but the variable will become global to window am I right ?

Comment: It seems you are looking for [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)

Comment: @Suchendra is there any downside at using module.exports in client app ? I thought it had better support than export default

Comment: @Tnargib `module.exports` is commonjs format pretty much specific to nodejs environment. If you want ES* compatible modules you have to use `import/export`. And a bundler (webpack, rollup) to convert your module to UMD format for old browsers.

Comment: @Tnargib, I am saying **there is no use of using the module.exports in client side application**. module.exports feature to be use in node js application which mocks the commonjs export/import module feature.

Comment: Well thanks a lot @YuryTarabanko, never knew about that. UMD seems pretty much what I needed, I'll give it a try !

Comment: @Tnargib, So you can achieve this by using javascript library called [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The subject is a bit old now but just in case someone get the same problem.

I got it working be using UMD as Yury suggested. After some unsuccessful tries I ended up using webpack directly. Never knew he was providing us these great tools to get UMD so simply. Here is my configuration file.

I export two configuration to build a normal and a minified version at the same time.

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/myLib.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "myLib.js",
        library: 'myLib',
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    mode: "development",
    module: config.module,
    resolve: config.resolve,
    plugins: config.plugins,
  },
  {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/myLib.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "myLib.min.js",
        library: 'myLib',
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    mode: "production",
    module: config.module,
    resolve: config.resolve,
    plugins: config.plugins,
  },
];
```